# Massive gap between text when I force my figures to appear where I wanted it to be in a two-column report

Tags: spacing, floats, two-column

I want the text to fill up the massive gap shown in the picture below:

[image: This is when I force it to appear on that page between the paragaraph I wanted it to be]

This is to code I used:

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{float}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\begin{subfigure}[c]{\linewidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{MutIscU_RSeq}
  \caption{subcaption 1}
  \label{fig: fortafix 11l-min}
\end{subfigure}
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}[c]{\linewidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{MutIscU_RSeq}
  \caption{Water circulated at 9 litres per minute}
  \label{fig: fortafix 9l-min}
\end{subfigure}
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}[c]{\linewidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{MutIscU_SeqQuality}
  \caption{Water circulated at 6 litres per minute}
  \label{fig: fortafix 6l-min}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Plate mould cooling with Fortafix flexseal 350 gap filler layer}
\label{fig: plate cooling fortafix traces}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

I tried adjusting the width of the subfigure and it works but the pictures are too small. If I increase from `.3\textwidth` to `.4\textwidth`, it either shows the gap as shown in the previous picture or appear at the end of the document. Here's the code I used that works:

```
\begin{figure}[hbt]
\centering
\begin{subfigure}[c]{.3\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{MutIscU_RSeq}
  \caption{subcaption 1}
  \label{fig: fortafix 11l-min}
\end{subfigure}
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}[c]{.3\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{MutIscU_RSeq}
  \caption{Water circulated at 9 litres per minute}
  \label{fig: fortafix 9l-min}
\end{subfigure}
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}[c]{.3\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{MutIscU_SeqQuality}
  \caption{Water circulated at 6 litres per minute}
  \label{fig: fortafix 6l-min}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Plate mould cooling with Fortafix flexseal 350 gap filler layer}
\label{fig: plate cooling fortafix traces}
\end{figure}
```

[image: The gap between text is now filled]

Anyone knows how to fill this gap while maximising the picture of my subfigures to span the whole one column? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Latex floats figures to avoid large gaps, using `[H]` stops floating and requests large gaps instead.

Comment: If I dont use H it wont appear where I wanted it to be but instead at the end of the document instead.

Comment: It is very hard to give suggestions if you only post fragments, replace you `\includegraphics` by `\rule{1cm}{2cm}` just for demonstration and make a complete document that shows the problem

Comment: It won't normally go to the end of the document unless you prevent it going anywhere else, but in anycase large spaces at page breaks are inevitable if you use `H` as the figure will not move relative to the surrounding text so if it needs to go over the page a gap is left, that's what `[H]` means.

Comment: Your second example for example uses `[hbt]` the main effect of that is that it prevents latex placing the float on a float page, as the argument does not include `p` so it makes it far more likely that the float can not be positioned and will thus be held until the end of the document.

Comment: Ok now I understand. I just started using Latex for a few days. Thanks for clearing that up. I put the 'p' and I managed to solve the problem. thank you so much! greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

figures  won't normally go to the end of the document unless you prevent them going anywhere else, but in anycase large spaces at page breaks are inevitable if you use `H` as the figure will not move relative to the surrounding text so if it needs to go over the page a gap is left, that's what `[H]` means.

Your second example for example uses `[hbt]` the main effect of that is that it prevents latex placing the float on a float page, as the argument does not include `p` so it makes it far more likely that the float can not be positioned and will thus be held until the end of the document.

Since the default figure option is `tbp` usually it is best to use no optional argument. if you do use one, to include `h` for example it is best to also include `p`. `[H]` is sometimes useful as a tool of last resort, but only sometimes:-)